# Filtering product collection and retrieving stock qty in a loop

Tags: php, simplexml, magento-1.9

I'm trying to write a stock import script to update inventory from a remote XML feed but I'm having trouble filtering my product collection in order to grab the current qty in stock.

I don't have a product ID or SKU in the feed, but do have product attributes, all of which combined, *will* find a unique product record, so I'm having to use these to filter my collection.

This is an example of the XML feed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<STOREITEMS>
<PRODUCT ITEM="786766786">
<STOCK>8</STOCK>
</PRODUCT>
<PRODUCT ITEM="766766867">
<STOCK>0</STOCK>
</PRODUCT>
<PRODUCT ITEM="768767868">
<STOCK Size="S/M" Color="White">2</STOCK>
<STOCK Size="M/L" Color="White">2</STOCK>
<STOCK Size="S/M" Color="Black">2</STOCK>
<STOCK Size="M/L" Color="Black">2</STOCK>
</PRODUCT>
<PRODUCT ITEM="897897897">
<STOCK>2</STOCK>
</PRODUCT>
</STOREITEMS>
```

so the attributes required to retrieve unique products in the example would be 'item', 'size' and 'color'.

and my code so far looks like this

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('*');

$xmldata = simplexml_load_file($remotefeed);
    
foreach ($xmldata->children() as $product) {

    $products->addFieldToFilter('item', strtolower($product['ITEM']));

    foreach ($product->STOCK as $feedQty) {

        $atts = $feedQty->attributes();

        if (!empty($atts)) {
            foreach ($atts as $key => $value) {
                $products->addFieldToFilter(strtolower($key), strtolower($value));
            }
        }

        $product = $products->load()->getFirstItem();
           
        $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product);

        $stockItem->setQty($feedQty);
        $stockItem->save();
    }
}
```

As I say, I am unable to filter the product collection and get the current stock on hand - $mageQty isn't returning anything at all.

I know it's likely I'm making several mistakes here but have so far failed to find guidance anywhere online that has helped - can anyone show me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Can you edit your question with an example of a unique product and the expected output?

Comment: In my example XML, each of the <STOCK> elements produces unique identifiers for 7 products, 4 share an 'item' value but, 'item' combined with 'size' and 'color' would be a unique combination of product attributes. What I wish for as far as output is to update the product's current Qty with the value in my XML.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on what you are trying to do, but if part of it is to extract the text value from each `<STOCK>` node, the following will extract them into an array which you can later use for whatever purpose.

Since you are dealing with xml, xpath is the best way of extracting data:

```
$string = <<<XML
//[your xml above]
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
$stocks = $xml->xpath("//PRODUCT/STOCK//text()");
foreach ($stocks as $stock) {
echo $stock , ' ';}
```

Output:

```
8 0 2 2 2 2 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your input but extracting the value of stock in the XML is not where I'm having problems I'm afraid. Where I'm struggling is with updating the product in Magento. I'm trying to (optimally because I have 5000 products in my catalogue) loop through the XML and, for each stock value, filter the Magento product collection, in order to update that value if need be. $stockItem->setQty($feedQty); is what isn't working. $stockItem is always empty.

Comment: @gpcola A key skill in debugging (and programming in general) is learning to break the problem down. In this case, you have two tasks: extracting the list of products from the XML; and putting them into Magento. If the XML part is working correctly, put it aside - take the output, hard-code it in an array, and feed that to your Magento code. If the output from the XML is _not_ correct, then put the Magento part aside - just echo out the list until you see the values you were expecting.